# Does "grep" have maximum of files it can handle?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, grep, cat

I just ran:

```
grep ""  *.txt > out.txt
```

on 1500 files. The output did only include a few hundred files.. Why?

When using:

```
cat  *.txt > out.txt
```

This works, but I want the filename as row name.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get an error message? There are multiple implementations of `grep`; does `grep --version` print anything useful? Were all the `*.txt` files actually text files?

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD. Yes, they are all the same type. No error.

Comment: Some are empty, does that matter?

Comment: Empty files shouldn't make any difference. Try this: `ls *.txt | wc -l ; grep "" *.txt | wc -l ; cat *.txt | wc -l` -- The first should tell you how many `*.txt` files you have; the second and third should give you the same result.

Comment: I get three values: 1452 2118 21634. The first one is the number of files. What is the other?

Comment: I ran it again now, and it worked.. Thanks all! Even though I did not do anything differently..

Comment: Odd behavior in grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD: if given a null pattern, the behavior changes when a file given as an argument contains a `=` in its name.  Files expanded in the glob after that file seem to be ignored.

Comment: If it failed and then succeeded for unknown reasons, it could easily fail again. It could be worth capturing the output of `grep "" *.txt` and `cat *.txt` in two separate files (if you can reproduce the problem) and looking more closely into how they differ. For the command I gave you, the first is the number of files, and the second and third *should* be the total number of lines in the files; you should get the same thing from `wc -l *.txt | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that all the files really show up in `cat *.txt > out`?  Unless you are right at the edge of the maximum number of characters per command, it should not make a difference.  Try this:

```
ls -1 | egrep '\.txt$' | xargs egrep "" /dev/null > out
```

`ls -1` lists all the files in the directory, one file name per line, and the first `egrep` filters out just the ones ending in ".txt".  This way, you don't have to worry about running out of command line length in listing the files.  `xargs` reads `stdin`, until it gets as many lines as it can fit on a single command line after the other arguments to `xargs`.  It then calls the command you provide with the options you provided with that set of input parameters.  `xargs` then repeats that process until it uses up all the arguments you provide.  Each invocation of the final `egrep` writes to the same `stdout`, so all the output goes to the same file.

The `/dev/null` is there in case `xargs` only finds one line of input (for example, becuase you only have one file or when bundling up files, the last bundle only has one file).  If you call `egrep` with a single file, it does not print the file name.  Since you specifically said you want the file names, telling `egrep` to search `/dev/null` guarantees there will always be at least two files.  Since `/dev/null` is guaranteed to be empty, you will never find anything in it, and it will not show up in your output.

`xargs` works great with `find`.  If you wanted to search for "foo" in all the ".txt" files in the current directory and its subdirectories:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs egrep foo /dev/null
```

would do the trick.  If you have file names with spaces in them, they won't get quoted and `egrep` will get confused, so use the `-print0` option on `find` and the `-0` option on xargs:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep foo /dev/null
```

Comment: If you add the `-H` flag to `egrep` you'll be able to drop the `/dev/null` argument.

Comment: @iscfrc Good tip.  I learned the /dev/null trick a number of years ago on a version of grep that did not have -H.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using:

```
ls -l *.txt | cut -b 51-
```

Also `*.txt` is expanded by your terminal before being passed to `cat` or `grep`. So yes, in theory there is a limit to how many file arguments you can pass to a command.

- `ls -l *.txt` gives you a list of files in the directory.
- `|` is a pipe and means you can pass the output of the previous command into the next one.
- `cut -b 51-` means you cut off the first 50 bytes and that gives you the filenames.

Comment: @user2966591 I just added an explanation. However Rubens' answer is much more elegant here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849001/1267329

Comment: Very good! What I ment was to include the filenames as a column in the new file. But now I can use this one and the cat command, then merge those. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, that does not work, because in every of the 1500 files there are more than one row! I want a column that tells which file it comes from.